# Mysql query using JOIN operator

Tags: mysql, join

I have two tables:  **progressdate** and **project**

Columns of table **progressdate**:

```
**id      name      progress       enddate**
  127     Rishi     Progress1     10/7/2015
  128     Sahil     Progress2     11/5/2015
  128     Sahil     Progress1     10/5/2015
  127     Rishi     Progress3     1/8/2015
  127     Rishi     Progress2     20/7/2015
```

Columns of table **project**:

```
**id      progress       file**
  127     Progress1       abc
  128     Progress2       xyz
```

Students have to upload their progress file into the project table.

I want to print the progress(ie *Progress1* or *Progress2* ) which has a minimum enddate which student of `id = 127` has not uploaded.

In this case `Rishi (id = 127)` has not uploaded the *Progress2* and *Progress3*, out of which enddate of *Progress2* is minimum, so output should be *Progress2*

This is what I've tried:

```
    SELECT pd.progress,enddate FROM progressdate pd LEFT JOIN project p  
    ON (pd.id=p.id)
    where pd.id="127"  and p.id="127" 
    and enddate = (
        select min(enddate)
        from progressdate pd
        LEFT JOIN project p ON pd.progress=p.progress
        where p.progress IS NULL)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select DISTINCT p1.progress 
from progressdate p1 LEFT JOIN project p2 
ON p1.id=p2.id
where p1.progress NOT IN (
              Select DISTINCT p1.progress 
              FROM progressdate p
              JOIN project p2 
              where p1.id=p2.id 
              and p1.id="127" 
              and p1.progress=p2.progress
              )
and p1.id="127"
order by enddate desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you

```
select * from progressdate p2
join
(select id, MIN(enddate) edate from progressdate p1
where progress NOT IN (Select Progress FROM project where p1.id=id)
group by id) tmp on p2.id=tmp.id and p2.enddate=tmp.edate
```

Comment: This gives *Progress3* for 127 not the expected *Progress2*, see SQLfiddle http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7bb22/2